# How to check if website is secure using PHP

Tags: php, html, iis, certificate, ssl-certificate

I'm quite new in security (certificates) and not understand how it works. 
I have `IIS` server and certificate is installed. I can open my website in two different ways:
`http://website` and
'https://website'.
When I open it as `http` then in address bar I can see that says website is not secure if i open it as `https` then padlock appears.
But I'm  not understand where is security in this case. How to control it with `php`?
I can check if site has `$_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'on'` and then let user to access but if i remove certificate from the server i still can access as 'https' but browser says that is not secure site but `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` still showing as `on`
How can i control security?

Comment: It isn't really up to PHP to know or care about how secure a client connection is.  On Nginx `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` isn't even accurate.  If you want to enforce HTTPS, then use `.htaccess` or Nginx configuration to `301` redirect from HTTP to HTTPS.

Comment: I think i understand now. So i can enable on IIS to force them use SSL.

Comment: Exactly, HTTPS should be handled by the HTTP server, PHP in this instance should only be responsible for authenticating user credentials and providing content.  BTW I think I totally glazed over the fact you are using IIS sorry lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you access a web page via [https](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol_Secure) the browser encodes you request with [SSL](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).
If you access a web page via [http](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) it is not encoded.
The certificate is just the proof for the user that the encoding is safe. The variable $_SERVER['HTTPS'] just says whether the user accessed the page via https or http.

Comment: Minor adjustment, the certificate is there as proof that the server being connected to is who they say they are.

Comment: So i can't identified with `php` if encoded with SSL then `ok` else denied?